# Operation timed out after 35007 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Tags: php, nginx, windows-7

I installed nginx1.10 and php5.6 on windows 7,but I found that when I access the page it was unable to make curl request to the same script which use the same listen port.

There was an curl request in `http://localhost/a.php`,it to make a curl request to `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`, but an error got `Error:Operation timed out after 35007 milliseconds with 0 bytes received`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root d:/localhost;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_localtime on;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}




http://localhost/a.php


<?php
function makeRequest($url, $params, $method = 'GET')
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($method == 'GET') {
        $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    }

    if (substr($url, 0, 6) == 'https:') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'ApiClient/v1.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 35);


    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($info);
    var_dump($error);
    return $result;
}


$url = 'http://localhost/phpinfo.php';
makeRequest($url, []);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://localhost/phpinfo.php?
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 96
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 35.007
    [namelookup_time] => 0.016
    [connect_time] => 0.219
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.219
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => 127.0.0.1
    [local_port] => 55978
)

D:\localhost\a.php:37:string 'Operation timed out after 35007 milliseconds with 0 bytes received' (length=66)
```

---

I have found that if you use a different port, the PHP that initiates the request uses the A port, and the response to the request's PHP uses another port, and the execution timeout does not occur.

Comment: Because php-cgi is not php-fpm, php-cgi will not automatically start the new process, so once occupied will be locked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why,Because php-cgi is not php-fpm, php-cgi will not automatically start the new process, so once occupied will be locked.